# Gradle + Scala Plugin + Zinc 1.3.5 leaks Protobuf 3.7 to the compiler classpath

Tags: scala, gradle, zinc

While debugging compilation errors of the generated Protobuf code after upgrading a Scala project to Gradle 6 & Zinc 1.3.5 I found that the compiler classpath contains two versions of the protobuf jar - the one I need (3.9.x) and 3.7. The latter is a dependency of the Zinc.

What is the correct way to run Zinc Scala build in Gradle without leaking its own dependencies to the classpath?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was resolved with sbt/zinc PR [799](https://github.com/sbt/zinc/pull/799) that was merged and included in the 1.4.0 release of Zinc.

With this MR they started shading the protobuf dependency (see [this commit](https://github.com/sbt/zinc/commit/3fbc8ec9d6e43bb519b294c68b978b2e753a518a#diff-5634c415cd8c8504fdb973a3ed092300b43c4b8fc1e184f7249eb29a55511f91R343)).

Unfortunately, it's not currently possible to use this version of Zinc with Gradle as Gradle issue [#15491](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/15491) was never resolved (note the issue title mentions Zinc 1.4.3 but applies for all versions of Zinc after the 1.3.x series).

It doesn't look like there's any plans to address #15491 but it looks like the issue will get solved as a side-effect of PR [18001](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/pull/18001) which is actively being developed with the intention of adding Scala 3 support to Gradle (and also involves cleaning up various long standing issues classpath related issues).